# Use MAMP Pro php.ini instead of OSX php

Tags: macos, mamp, php, apc

I'm having a problem running a command in php using APC in my mac. In the MAMP Pro i have it on but looks like my mac is not using MAMP's php but using osx'.

Any idea about how to tell my mac to use MAMP Pro instead of OSX' php.ini?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `MAMP Pro` `PHP` executable should be located in `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.x.x/bin/`.

The `OSX` `PHP` is located in `/usr/bin/php` and `/usr/bin` is in `PATH` variable by default.

One way to make `OSX` use `MAMP` `PHP` is to add `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.x.x/bin/` to your `PATH` variable (before `/usr/bin`):

Simply edit `~/.profile` (ie. open `Terminal.app`, type `vim ~/.profile`) and add the following line to end of the file:

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.x.x/bin/:$PATH
```

Note that you should replace `x`s in `php5.x.x` with the `MAMP Pro` `PHP` version.

Comment: Thank you Fardjad. I have this two lines in my .profile now. I also have the .bash_profile.. don't know if that is a problems. 

export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin/:$PATH
alias php="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin/php"

This are also my paths and i made chmod +x php in there. When i run php --ini it says it's in /private/etc/php.ini 

I'm still trying to load apc but nothing yet :(

Comment: Alright, i needed a restart! Now i get the right paths when i run the command php --ini but can't load the apc extension :( anyway thank you!